# This classifier didn't work with my samples

Tags: classification, random-forest, assets, training-data, google-earth-engine

The GEE show me the message "No valid training data were found"

Can someone show me which part of the code is wrong??

```
var gt_samples = ee.FeatureCollection(solo_exposto.merge(campo_pasto).merge(Cerrado_Esparso).merge(Cerrado_Denso).merge(Agua));


//Zoom to the ROI
Map.centerObject(roi,12)

//Add NICFI Planet basemap

var vis = {"bands":["R","G","B"],"min":150,"max":1600,"gamma":1.1};
var viscir = {"bands":["N","R","G"],"min":[400,400,400],"max":[5100,1800,1600],"gamma":1.3}; 

// Filter basemaps by date and get the first image from filtered results
Map.addLayer(PL_bands, vis, 'Planet mosaic',false);
Map.addLayer(PL_bands, viscir, 'Planet mosaic CIR',false);

//Create a legend on the display
{
//Final classification palette (20220127)
var palette = [ 
  '#36a911',     //(0) Woodlands
  '#ffc10f',    //(1) Shrubs
  '#75ff1f',     //(2) Grasslands
  'c0894b',     //(3) Croplands
  '#a3a3a3',     //(4) Built-up 
  '#fbff21',     //(5) Bare soil         
  '#13c8ff'    //(6) Water
];

// name of the legend
var names = ['Woodlands', 'Shrubs', 'Grasslands', 'Croplands', 'Built-up', 'Bare soil', 'Water'];

// set position of panel
var legend = ui.Panel({
  style: {
    position: 'bottom-left',
    padding: '8px 15px'
  }
});
 
// Create legend title
var legendTitle = ui.Label({
  value: 'Legend',
  style: {
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: '18px',
    margin: '0 0 4px 0',
    padding: '0'
    }
});
 
// Add the title to the panel
legend.add(legendTitle);


// Creates and styles 1 row of the legend.
var makeRow = function(color, name) {
 
      // Create the label that is actually the colored box.
      var colorBox = ui.Label({
        style: {
          backgroundColor: color,
          // Use padding to give the box height and width.
          padding: '8px',
          margin: '0 0 4px 0'
        }
      });
 
      // Create the label filled with the description text.
      var description = ui.Label({
        value: name,
        style: {margin: '0 0 4px 6px'}
      }); 
 
      // return the panel
      return ui.Panel({
        widgets: [colorBox, description],
        layout: ui.Panel.Layout.Flow('horizontal')
      });
};
// Add color and and names
for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  legend.add(makeRow(palette[i], names[i]));
  }  
// add legend to map (alternatively you can also print the legend to the console)
Map.add(legend);
}

/*
//List of all available bands
0: "B", float, EPSG:4326, 72188x45314 px //Planet band
1: "G", float, EPSG:4326, 72188x45314 px //Planet band
2: "R", float, EPSG:4326, 72188x45314 px //Planet band
3: "N", float, EPSG:4326, 72188x45314 px //Planet band
4: "NDVI_p", float ∈ [-1, 1], EPSG:4326, 75553x48721 px //Planet vegetation index
5: "NDWI_p", float ∈ [-1, 1], EPSG:4326, 75553x48721 px //Planet vegetation index
0: "B2", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median band 
1: "B3", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median band 
2: "B4", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median band 
3: "B8", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median band 
4: "B11", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median band 
5: "B12", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median band 
6: "NDWI", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median vegetation index 
7: "NDVI", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px  //S2 median vegetation index 
8: "NDMI", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median vegetation index 
9: "BSI", float, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S2 median vegetation index 
10: "VH", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S1 median band
11: "VV", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //S1 median band
12: "T1", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
13: "T2", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
14: "T3", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
15: "T4", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
16: "T5", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
17: "T6", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
18: "T7", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
19: "T8", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
20: "T9", double, EPSG:4326, 36095x22658 px //Plantscope textural band
*/


//Selection of bands for classification

//var finalbands = ["B",'G',"R",'N','NDVI_p','NDWI_p',"T1","T3","T4","T5"] // OB_PL - Planet bands, indices and textures
var finalbands = ["B",'G',"R",'N',"B8",'B11','B12',"NDVI_p","NDWI_p","BSI",'NDMI','VV','VH','VV_VH',"T1",'T2','T3',"T4","T5"] // OB_PLS2S1 - Planet & S2 & S1 bands and indices and GLCM Planet textures


//Merge all the spectral and textural bands from Planet, S2, S1 removing clusters from S2
var compclip = PL_bands.addBands(s2s1_bands.select(s2s1_bands.bandNames().remove("clusters")))

print(compclip,'Dataset with all glcm features')

//Show clusters
Map.addLayer(PL_bands.select('clusters'),'','Planet spatial clusters',false)

//Select bands for classification of objects
var features = compclip.select(ee.List(finalbands).add('clusters'))

print(features,'Objects with selected features')

//calculate mean values of bands at the object level
var objects_mean = features.reduceConnectedComponents({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  labelBand: 'clusters'
})

//Define the classification features bands removing  the "clusters" bands
var features = objects_mean.bandNames().remove("clusters")
print(features,'Selected features for classification')

//Show GT samples
print (gt_samples,'GT point samples')
Map.addLayer(gt_samples,'','GT point samples',false);

//Create a column containing random numbers

gt_samples = gt_samples.randomColumn('rand',1)


// Get the predictors into the table and create a training dataset based on "LULC" property
var datasamp = objects_mean.select(features).sampleRegions({
  collection: gt_samples,
  properties: ['lulc','rand'],
  scale: 5,
  tileScale: 10,
  geometries:false
});


print('Data sampling',datasamp);

var training = datasamp.filterMetadata('rand', 'less_than', 0.7);
var val = datasamp.filterMetadata('rand', 'not_less_than', 0.7);

//Training a Random Forest Classifier
var classifier = ee.Classifier.smileRandomForest(200).train({
  features: training,
  classProperty: 'lulc',
  inputProperties: finalbands
});

var classified = objects_mean.select(finalbands).classify(classifier);
Map.addLayer(classified,{min: 0, max: 6, palette: palette},'OB_classification', true);
print("OB classification",classified)


//Explain the feature importance

var dict = classifier.explain();
print("Importance of feature in the RF classification",dict);
var variable_importance = ee.Feature(null, ee.Dictionary(dict).get('importance'));
var mm = dict.get('outOfBagErrorEstimate');
print(mm)

 
var chart =
  ui.Chart.feature.byProperty(variable_importance)
    .setChartType('ColumnChart')
    .setOptions({
      title: 'Random Forest Variable Importance',
      legend: {position: 'none'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Bands'},
      vAxis: {title: 'Importance'}
    });
print(chart);

print(dict.get("importance"))

//Validation
var val_subset = val.classify(classifier);
var testAccuracy = val_subset.errorMatrix('lulc', 'classification');

print('Confusion matrix: ', testAccuracy);
print('Test accuracy: ', testAccuracy.accuracy());


//Build a feature collection to export the CF to a csv file
var testArray = testAccuracy.array().toList()
var keys = ['0' ,'1', '2', '3', '4','5','6']
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection(testArray.map(function(item) {
  var properties = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, item)
  return ee.Feature(null, properties)
}))
//print(fc,'Export matrix')
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: fc,
  folder: 'gee_out',
  description: 'exportAccuracy',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});

var precision = testAccuracy.producersAccuracy().transpose();
var recall = testAccuracy.consumersAccuracy();
print("Producer Accuracy (Precision) for each class", precision)
print("User Accuracy (Recall) for each class", recall)

//Compute the F-score for each class
var fscore = precision.multiply(recall).divide(precision.add(recall)).multiply(2)
print("F-score for each class", fscore)

//Compute whole Precision
var PA_mean = precision.reduce({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  axes: [1]
}).get([0,0])
print("Average Producer Accuracy (Precision) ", PA_mean)

//Compute whole Recall
var UA_mean = recall.reduce({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  axes: [1]
}).get([0,0])
print("Average User Accuracy (Recall) ", UA_mean)

//Compute whole F1-score
var total_fscore = PA_mean.multiply(UA_mean).divide(PA_mean.add(UA_mean)).multiply(2)
print('Average F-score',total_fscore)


//Export classification to Drive
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: classified,
  description: 'OB_classification',
  folder: 'gee_out',
  region: roi,
  scale: 5,
  crs: 'EPSG:32723'
});

//Export the classified validation dataset to drive (for the McNemar test)
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: val_subset,
  folder: 'gee_out',
  description: 'table_out',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

This scripts works fine with this assets
https://code.earthengine.google.com/0914dd2be350cdf772ef872beebb9807

but doesn't works with these
https://code.earthengine.google.com/403c7cbe83b620ddb02dd7f832f5edd5

i tried to convert my imageCollection points to a table, but this isn't work. i think i need to do some conversion in my points data to works.